# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on the same host url

Tags: javascript

In my javascript I have

```
client.base_url = "https://qp-t3.herokuapp.com";

var url = client.base_url + "/account/new?name=" + client.name;

    http.get({
        url: url,
        onload: function() { 
            account = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            client.account = account;
            client.findGame();
        }
        });
}
```

and I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://qp-t3.herokuapp.com/account/new?name=rstrsrtsrt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://qp-t3.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I see that's because I'm sending http. I'm using http.min.js.

How do I send https?

EDIT: the http.min.js library, when I call http.get with that base url, converts to HTTP.

I will try using the :// trick

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://qp-t3.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://qp-t3.herokuapp.com/account/new?name=v'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: *"How do I send https?"* Not sure what you mean. You are requesting `https` but it seems you loaded the page with `http`. If your server is configured for https, then just use https to open the page.

Comment: Do what the error message tells you: send the header that will allow access from `http://qp-t3.herokuapp.com` (if you really want to load the main page through http but ajax through https).

Comment: Acutally I think this is a misunderstanding - it's not that you are SENDING http, but that the source page (the context in which the `http.get()` call is executed) was accessed via http. So you will probably either want to force the user of the page to the https location, or have some code to detect whether the user is on http or https and use the appropriate `base_url`

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly is right. I'd personally lean towards the first option of forcing the page to load in https in the first place. However, if you go with the second option, instead of writing code you can use `base_url = "//qp-t3.herokuapp.com";`, which will automatically use the protocol the user is currently using. (i.e. http -> http or https -> https).

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly, if you visit https://qp-t3.herokuapp.com/ you can see the error in the console (enter foo in the textfield and click register).

Comment: If the `://` trick doesn't work, you can use `document.location.protocol` which will return `http:` or `https:`.

Comment: I can't actually - I get that username is undefined but I do not see any cross domain errors in the browser. (LOTS of warnings about a lack of board though :p)

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly you were right -- I had missed that the base url wasn't set to HTTPS. Able to load in normal browser now!